# What tools to use for developing flash/flex based touch screen user interface for embedded system

Tags: flash, embedded

We are looking at developing a device with a touch screen and an embedded PC like computer for the user interface.

What are the benefits and disadvantages of using flash/flex for this user interface development?

One of our goals is to seperate the design (= look and feel) and the functionality of the application to ease the development.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Flash

Pros:

- Readily available
- Powerful editing tools
- Lots of people know how to use it

Cons:

- (Very) bad performance in contrast to what it does
- Open source implementations still lagging
- Use of Adobe's flash component is regulated by their EULA
- Does not offer a clear cut API for embedding